# Linq left outer join onto same list to find leaf nodes

Tags: c#, linq, tree

I have an in memory `List<TreeNode>`. Is it possible to to use linq to select all leaf nodes?

The SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT      
    t1.Name
FROM 
    Tree t1 
    LEFT JOIN Tree t2 
        ON t1.UserId = t2.ParentId  
WHERE 
    t2.UserId is null
```

The closest that I've got is (i still need to filter out the nulls):

```
                       var test = from t1 in list
                       join t2 in list
                       on t1.UserId equals t2.ParentId into g                   

                       from result in g.DefaultIfEmpty()          

                       select new { 
                       t1.Name
                       };
```

Which produces the correct sql (when testing in linqpad) without the where clause. I can't access t2 where I select the anonymous object of if I try to filter results on where t2 == null. Do I need to create a copy of the list and join onto that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I'd misunderstood before. So you're basically after items (`t1`) in the list where there isn't no element `t2` such that `t1.UserId == t2.ParentId`? In that case, I suggest you use:

I suspect you want:

```
var test = from t1 in list
           join t2 in list
              on t1.UserId equals t2.ParentId into g
           where !g.Any()
           select t1.Name;
```

Note that I'm not using an anonymous type here as you're only selecting a single value.

Another alternative would be:

```
var parents = new HashSet<Guid>(list.Where(x => x.ParentId != null)
                                    .Select(x => x.ParentId.Value));
var query = list.Where(t1 => !parents.Contains(t1.UserId));
```

Comment: should have clarified - producing the correct sql when running the query in linqpad

Comment: this produces                                                    `SELECT [t0].[Name]
FROM [Tree] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Tree] AS [t1] ON (([t0].[UserId]) = [t1].[ParentId]) AND (0 = 1)`

Comment: @woggles: That seems pretty odd... but what does it do in your actual scenario of using it on a list? What's the type of `UserId` in your case?

Comment: When using it on the list it just returns all the names from the 1st list. UserId and ParentId are both System.Guid (only ParentId is Nullable) - I guess this could be the problem? DB Mapping was done using EF4.1.

Comment: @woggles: Okay, I misunderstood the == null part. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var test = from t1 in list
           join t2 in list
           on t1.UserId equals t2.ParentId into g                   
           from result in g.DefaultIfEmpty()          
           where t2.UserId == null
           select new { 
               t1.Name
           };
```

Comment: The name 't2' doesnt exist in the current context

Comment: @woggles. The problem is that you want results when UserId is null and you are applying join using the same null value (null equals t2.ParentId). This null value is causing problem. You don't require a null check in where clause. It is already dealt by DefaultIfEmpty